# aspx insert to Oracle get ORA-01008 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

I have created table in Oracle 11g,

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE1" 
(
    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)
```

connect with `System.Data.OleDb`, the `connectionStrings` is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnStr" connectionString="Provider=msdaora;Data Source=test;User Id=test;Password=test;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and try to insert data into table `TABLE1`:

```
private void testInsert()
{
    string sql = "";
    int recordsAffected = 0;

    using (OleDbConnection openCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        sql = @"insert into table1 (column1, column2) values (:aaa, :bbb)";
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql))
        {
            command.Connection = openCon;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":aaa", "test");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bbb", "0123456");

            openCon.Open();
            recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <-- error here
            openCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

but get `ORA-01008` error at `command.ExecuteNonQuery ()` line. Why is Oracle claiming that not all variables are bound?

If I replace the colon (`:`) prefix with `@`, I got `ORA-00936` error. And if I remove all prefix, I got `ORA-00984` error. What is the correct way to insert data into Oracle table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to switch to opd.net and remove `:` like so `Parameters.Add("aaa","test");`

Answer (score 0):

You dont OLEDB. Look into the link below
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm#t3

Comment: Is it not possible to use OLEDB with Oracle?